# Text Input Dialog in javafx is freezing my frame

Tags: java, javafx, controller, dialog

First of all, this method allow me to generate a **sub-frame** that returns a **String** of what the user has typed

When i call the method, there is a **text field** and two buttons which are " **OK** " and " **Cancel** ", the problem is when i hit **cancel** the sub-frame **close** leaving the **main frame** freezing and won't respond at all ! i tried many ways to evade this issue, but without any result

can you please help me to figure out a solution ?
it seems to be some kind of an **exeption**, here is the stacktrace : QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Supplier) line: not available

and here is the method :

```
    public static String showTextInput(String alertTitle, String title, String message, String defaultValue) {
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog(defaultValue);
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    dialog.setTitle(alertTitle);
    dialog.setHeaderText(title);
    dialog.setContentText(message);

    Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent()) {
        return result.get();
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And thank you for your time

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example which we can use in order to reproduce the error. Also edit your answer and show us the full stacktrace error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, while i was generating the code for you ( JKostikiadis ) i accidently figured out where was the problem !

i was testing my result String of null value like this : **result.equals(null)**
and the compiler didn't mind about it, but when i changed it to **result == null**
,the problem was gone !

so it wasn't a problem of the input dialog finally, but a **string problem**

Comment: It's very common to fix simple problems like that by trying to reproduce the error on a new example. Also by far (imo) the best debugging way is the `System.out.println` to print flags and condition to be sure that everything is working right. I am glad you find the error.

Comment: well, that's exactly what i did to find the error !
i was sure that the method could return null, but the solution wouldn't come to my mind till i tried to print the string value, thank you for your help :)